# I am using idle for python but the main function is not executing properly, can someone tell me on this where am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

PFB Code it's giving me only the number but its not executing the function inside the main function

```
def factorial(n):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)

def main():
    n = int(input("Enter the number : "))
    factorial(n)

main()
```

output:

```
Enter the number: 8
8
```

Comment: Yeah… you're neither returning nor printing the result…!?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result from `factorial`:

```
def main():
    n = int(input("Enter the number : "))
    return factorial(n)
```

Comment: still getting the same result.  Enter the number : 5
>>>

Comment: Are you doing this interactively or by calling the script directly? In the latter case replace the `return factorial(n)` with `print(factorial(n))`.

Comment: Yeah its working now. Thank u  but can u please explain me why its not working in case of returning just for my understanding thanks in advance :)

Comment: To print something to the screen, you need to use `print`. `return` just gives the result back to the called, in that case the place where you wrote `main()`. In the interactive console, results are printed automatically when they are at the top level. The interactive console is also called REPL: read-eval-*print*-loop.